# Bootstrap - align column text elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to align to right 2 'h' elements (i.e. h1 and h3) inside right Bootstrap column.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">photo</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
<h1>Header</h1>
<h3 style="width:100px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</h3>
</div>
```

The issue is that h3 with fixed width isn't aligned to right while h1 snippet is. See [screen](http://take.ms/CcOpk)

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zdx6c1s/2/)

After debugging I came to find out that the issue was due to h1 width property. But I need it to keep the text folding. It can be solved by manually setting left margin but I am sure there is a more elegant solution.

Why is the width property keeps text from aligning and what are the solution?

Comment: It may help to see your CSS but in general, everything is aligned left by default and if its not filling the screen you need to float or position it to the right

Comment: Do you want to make h3 align to left?

Comment: @Mehmood I want both of them to align to right.

Comment: Can't you just use `pull-right` on the `h3` like so: [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zjcryfkx/) ?

Comment: @DavidDomain exactly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following block.

**CSS:**

```
h1, h3{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3zdx6c1s/4/ - still not exactly what I want. Moreover, header started to fold.

Comment: i think you have changed "text-right" to "pull-right"  and if you want to stop fold just remove "word-wrap: break-word". If this still don't work please come with better explanation of your requirements.

Comment: I want both h elements to be aligned to right. In your fiddle they aren't aligned so. See: http://take.ms/fF9F1

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3zdx6c1s/7/ I don't know your complete scenario, but if you still face some issue as per your scenario then i suggest you use col- classes on Headings.